# Is there a way to remotely monitor a specific Android application?

Tags: android, remote-access, remote-debugging, remote-desktop

There is an android application I am planning to write, that will be used as an "always on" application (kiosk-mode) used on Android tablets running restaurant menu. Today, I already have a rudimentary application, but it is not quite what might qualify as kiosk-mode, since sometimes users close the application.

I wanted to see if there is a way to monitor the application remotely (or on device itself) and automatically restart it, s.t. it comes the foreground application ?

Of course, I'd prefer to remotely monitor for some remote customer service. It is not exactly essential to view (in remote desktop / vnc sense), but gather information like application health (running in foreground or not), get it's logs etc. Now I understand that on an unrooted device an applications log is not visible to other applications. So I was wondering if I could design my application to create light logs or status information, in a non-standard way, that could be shared by my other monitoring application.

While I get a feel that I am reinventing the wheel, since requirements like these seem far-from-unique, but in my search haven't found much beyond the standard 'screen cast' / 'screen share' applications... most of which either don't work too well (especially without root), or need one to jump through hoops to get them working.

Comment: Create a service that runs in the background, minimize its main activity will only hides it until the user clicks the "quit app" menu option with a password, for example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are ways to monitor activities of your application. There are utilities available to help you keep logs of events carried out by the users of the application. Like getting statistical information. They are typically Mobile Analytics tools.

Check this for instance: https://mixpanel.com/

This for example can help to keep track of events fired by the application. You can even send mails and notification to the users. There are similar tools available. For instance [Google Analytics for Mobile Apps](https://www.google.com.bd/analytics/)

The other possibility is to use Google Cloud Messaging. I believe this is even more powerful, which may help us to control our application to some extent. You may find this of help: http://hmkcode.com/android-google-cloud-messaging-tutorial/